# Cross domain loading of widget template

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am hosting a widget on another domain than the site in which I am embedding the widget.

The dashboard.js loads fine, but the HTML template gets,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.72:8081/widgets/templates/dashboard.html. Origin http://192.168.2.72:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The url to the template is correct, so I can only assume this is a cross domain error.  In the widget, the template is referred to like:

```
templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl("monitor/dashboard", "../templates/dashboard.html"),
```

This all works when it's a local widget.  Is there anyway to get dojo to load the HTML template in better way?

The way I have defined loader,

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: 0, dojoBlankHtmlUrl: '/blank.html', parseOnLoad:true,
             packages: [
                   {name: 'monitor', location: 'http://192.168.2.72:8081' + '/widgets'},
             ]"
             src="/media/scripts/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know this doesn't work on newer versions of chrome to prevent XSS, though there seem to be [ways to get around it](http://blog.securitee.org/?p=37).

Comment: @Huey I think there must be a better way to do it

Comment: Well, you could try using `iframes`.

Comment: @Huey can we build dojo widget template?? would this solve issue>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several ways to solve it.

The first solution is a serverside solution by using CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing). If you can set the CORS headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Your browser will detect this and will allow the XMLHttpRequest.

---

While this solution is probably the best, you could also use some alternatives, for example by using JSONP (for example with `dojo/request/script`). However, using JSONP also means that you cannot use a plain HTML template, but you have to convert your HTML template to a JavaScript string.

If you then use the `templateString` property, you can then pass the template as a string, in stead of specifying the path.

---

The `templateString` property also allows you to build your template, if you can build your template as a JavaScript string, then you could build your template, for example by using Grunt and the grunt-html-convert task.

---

You might be able to do a similar thing with the Dojo build system by using depsScan. This build transform should scan modules and convert legacy code to AMD and it should also look for things like `dojo.cache()`, `dojo.moduleUrl()` and `templatePath` and convert it to `templateString`.

Look at the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/transforms/depsScan.html) for more info.

---

the last (and also pretty common) solution is to use a reverse proxy. If you have to host your HTML templates on a different domain, you can still define a reverse proxy in your HTTP server and redirect certain calls to a different domain, for example (Apache 2):

```
ProxyPass           /templates  http://other-domain.com
ProxyPassReverse    /templates  http://other-domain.com
```

This allows you to go to `/templates/my-template.html`, which will be redirected to `http://other-domain.com/my-template.html`.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri. Cant I use util build to build widget?(This is what suggested by my team member bare if wrong)

Comment: Using `build.sh` from dojo utils?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm not familiar with the Dojo build system, though I suppose you could do it with the depsScan build transform. It converts legacy code to AMD and will look for `templatePath` stuff and convert it to `templateString`, so I suppose it should be capable of "building" your template.

Comment: can you share some references or docs on how to use `depsScan`?

Comment: I have no idea (never used it before), but I found this doc: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/build/transforms/depsScan.html which says that, by setting the `internStrings` property to `true`, it will intern all strings (for example template paths to strings).

Comment: Thanks for being so much supportive. Really appreciated.