# How to build a custom widget using dojo build.sh

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

Referencing the question [Cross domain loading of widget template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239453/cross-domain-loading-of-widget-template),

I want to build my template based custom widget using dojo build system (Just to get rid of xDomain errors).

I am not able to understand how to do it,

My Custom `dashboard.js` widget,

```
define([
     "dojo/_base/declare",
     "dijit/_WidgetBase",
     "dojox/dtl/_Templated",
], function (
        declare,
        WidgetBase,
        TemplatedMixin,
   ) {
   // rest of code and function 
   templateString: dojo.cache("myWidget.dashboard", "../templates/dashboard.html")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, if you are using the `define()`/`require()` pattern (AMD), you *usually* shouldn't see `dojo.xyz` or `dijit.xyz` anywhere in your code.

The old dojo.cache template strings should now be loaded using the `dojo/text` module, just like any other dependency.

So instead you would have something like:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dojox/dtl/_Templated",
    "dojo/text!myWidget/templates/dashboard.html"
], function (
    declare,
    WidgetBase,
    TemplatedMixin,
    myTemplateString
){
   // rest of code and function 
   templateString: myTemplateString
});
```